# Using frameworks in Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode

Tags: java, spring, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Is it possible (and are there any examples of that) to use Java frameworks inside Hyperledger Fabric Java chaincode?

For now, I have a relatively complex smart contract and want to utilize Spring State Machine to handle it's state transitions. Spring State Machine plays nicely with Spring Framework and it's very easy and convenient to bind actions of State Machine to Spring Beans.

The question is - how to build Facbric Chaincode as Spring Application (no web part, ofc) and is it a good/bad design to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is exactly my question. Have you found the answer?

Comment: Yes. I managed to use spring in Fabric Chaincode. It's actually really simple. You have a main method, so you can just instantiate spring boot headless application (without web) and just start a chaincode class as a spring bean

Comment: Can you post the complete example here please